# SUM sqlite column values (android)

Tags: android, database, sqlite, sum

I need help with summing all the values in one of the columns(`KEY_CONTENT6`) in my database(`MYDATABASE_TABLE`). I keep having force close issues, somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong!

Heres my code:

```
public Cursor sumAll(){

 float columntotal = 0;
 Cursor cursor1 = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(
     "SELECT SUM("+Float.valueOf(KEY_CONTENT6)+") FROM MYDATABASE_TABLE", null);
       if(cursor1.moveToFirst()) {
         columntotal = cursor1.getFloat(0);
     }
   cursor1.close();

 String  sumtotal = Float.toString((float)columntotal);           

  return cursor1;

 }
```

The column `KEY_CONTENT6` is a string for various reasons which is why I used `Float.valueOf()` but I'm guessing that's where my problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're closing the cursor then returning it.  You probably want to return the column total or sum total, not the cursor